# Python Pandas: How to exclude rows that have any value repeated more than n times

Tags: python, pandas

I'm pretty green when it comes to Python so my apologies if this is an obvious question.

I have a dataframe that has 8 columns. For each row the first four columns are single names. The following four columns are locations that each one of those names are associated with. Here's an example.

| name1 | name2 | name3 | name4 | loc1 | loc2 | loc3 | loc4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Dave | Aaron | Alex | NYC | CHI | ANN | FAL |
| Erica | Alana | Steve | Blake | JAX | MIA | JAX | JAX |
| Stacy | Tom | Nancy | Steph | SAC | SFR | DAL | DAL |

All I want to do is take that dataframe and create a new one that shows all the same information but excludes any rows that have more than two of the same location in the last 4 columns. and then the result needs to have the index reset. So the result of the example above would be:

| name1 | name2 | name3 | name4 | loc1 | loc2 | loc3 | loc4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Joe | Dave | Aaron | Alex | NYC | CHI | ANN | FAL |
| Stacy | Tom | Nancy | Steph | SAC | SFR | DAL | DAL |

I was trying to make it work with a combination of apply, groupby and count but could not get it to work right. I feel like there's a simple solution.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df.filter(like = 'loc').nunique(axis = 1) > 2]
```

Output:

```
   name1 name2  name3  name4 loc1 loc2 loc3 loc4
0    Joe  Dave  Aaron   Alex  NYC  CHI  ANN  FAL
2  Stacy   Tom  Nancy  Steph  SAC  SFR  DAL  DAL
```

Using `filter` with `like = 'loc'` to limit the dataframe columns to just the last four or the loc columns, then get the number of unique values with `axis=1` using `nunique`, the create a boolean series and with boolean filtering we can select correct rows.

Comment: That did it! You're my hero! Both answers worked but the lamda function seemed to slow things down over a large dataframe. Thank you both!

Comment: @EdC You're welcome.  Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nunique` on each row:

```py
df[df[['loc1', 'loc2', 'loc3', 'loc4']].apply(lambda x: len(x) - x.nunique() < 2, axis=1)].copy().reset_index()
```